# Suppose $A \subset S$ and both $A$ and $S$ are regular surfaces. Show that $A$ is open in $S$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Suppose $A \subset S$ and both $A$ and $S$ are regular surfaces. Show that $A$ is open in $S$ (w/ respect to subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Note that the definition of a regular surface $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that for every point $p \in S$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $p$ and an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that there is $x:U \to V \cap S$ is a homeomorphism, is differentiable, and its differential is one to one.

So I am trying to show that for every point $p \in A$, it is in the interior of $A$, with respect to subspace topology on $S$. That is $p$ is in the set $V^{'}\cap S \subset A$ where $V^{'}$ open in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Since $A$ is regular surface, there is a open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $p$ and an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that there is $x:U\to V \cap S$ is a homeomorphism, etc.

I am referring to this link here where I am not quite sure how he concludes the last part: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2002;task=show_msg;msg=0003.0001.0001.0001

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4386841/269050.

Answer (score 3):

The Inverse Function Theorem tells you that a smooth map with invertible derivative is an open map. I'm skeptical about your definition, by the way; I've never seen a definition that says "differentiable" rather than $C^1$. The latter is absolutely needed for applications of the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: how would I use inverse function theorem? Please elaborate.

Comment: Apply it to $x_S^{-1}\circ x_A$, mapping an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Sorry but I am still not getting it. How does this show that p is in an open set in S contained in A?

Comment: Because the mapping I wrote down is an open map. This means precisely that $x_A(V)$ is open in $S$ for $V$ open in $U$. Perhaps it would help to remind you that the only $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$ is an open subset.

Comment: Why is $x_A(V)$ open in $S$?

Comment: Because $x_S$ is a homeomorphism and $x_A(V)=x_S\big(x_S^{-1}\circ x_A(V)\big)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. So is $x_s^{-1} \circ x_a(V)$ open in the domain of $x_S$?

Comment: Yes. By the open mapping consequence of the IFT.

Comment: Yes. Great, I'll try to think about this some more for a few minutes and see if I have anymore questions. Thanks.

Comment: @TedShifrin May you explain why we can apply IFT to $x_S^{-1}\circ x_A$? I don't know how to prove its partial derivatives are linearly independent. I know $x_S$ and $x_A$ have linearly independent partial derivatives, but I am not sure how to use this fact. Do we have to consider the continuous inclusion map from $A$ to $S$?

Comment: @user5527: This is an application of the chain rule. (Officially, you need to know that $x_S^{-1}$ has a local $C^1$ extension to a map. It all depends on your approach to the subject.) The composition of injective linear maps is injective.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you explain more? Here is my thought. Let $i: A \to S, p \in A $. Then near $p$, we know $dx_A, di, dx_S$ are nonsingular. Since $x_S$ is locally a diffeomorphism, $dx_S ^{-1} $ is nonsingular at $p$. Hence if we let $h= x_S^{-1}\circ i \circ x_A$, we have $dh= dx_S^{-1}\circ di \circ dx_A$, which is nonsingular. Thus we can apply IFT. Is my argument correct?

Comment: @user5527: Not quite right. $x_S\colon U\to\Bbb R^3$ is $C^1$ , where $U\subset\Bbb R^2$ is open. $x_S$ has injective derivative, but it's only a diffeomorphism *to its image*. Your using the term "nonsingular" is definitely not right, unless you consider maps only to images. Even to discuss $dx_S^{-1}$, you need a local smooth extension of $x_S^{-1}$, and then it's of course no longer a diffeomorphism.