# Why does a regular surface contained in a sphere have to be open in the sphere?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I'm reading the book *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* written by do Carmo. And there is one theorem I'm trying to prove. Here is the statement:

*If $S$ be a compact, connected, regular surface with constant Gaussian curvature $K$, then $S$ is a sphere.*

[image]

> In the proof, do Carmo claims that $S$ is open in the sphere $\Sigma$. But I'm quite vague about his argument. Why is $S$ open in $\Sigma$ if $S$ is to be a regular surface? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\in S$. Since $S$ is a regular surface, there exists an open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ and a homeomorphism $\psi: U\to \psi(U)\subseteq S$ such that $\psi(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ containing $p$. So $\Sigma\cap \psi(U)$ is an open subset of $\Sigma$ containing $p$.

Comment: Thanks. But, is $U$ an open set in $\mathbb R^2$? Also, do you conclude open-ness of $S$ by letting $p$ range over $S$ (thus, $S$ can be written as a union of open sets)?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that was a typo. And your argument is correct.

Comment: Be aware that, according to the definition of parameterization, $\psi(U)$ is open in $S$, i.e., there exists $V$ open in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\psi(U)=V\cap S$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4386841/269050) for another proof of this fact.