Given that $A\subset S$ are both regular surfaces, show that $A$ is open in the topology of $S$.
Exercise 14 of section 2-4 of (the Dover published translation of) do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" asks to show that a subset $A\subset S$ of a regular surface $S$ is regular iff $A$ is open in $S$ (where we take $S$ to have the subspace topology induced by it living in $\mathbb{R}^3$). I am struggling with the forward implication.
For reference, do Carmo defines a regular surface as a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for each $p\in S$, there is a neighbourhood $p \in V\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and a onto parametrisation $\mathbf{x}: U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to V\cap S$ (where $U$ is open) such that $\mathbf{x}$ is a smooth homeomorphism with one-to-one differential $d\mathbf{x}_q$ at each $q\in U$.
I have referred to two previous answers https://math.stackexchange.com/a/711633/195586 (due to Ted Shifrin) and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4386841/195586 (due to Leandro Caniglia) of essentially the same question. I am reasking the question as Caniglia's answer uses slightly more sophisticated language than is available at this point in do Carmo's text, and I am unsure if I am interpreting the sketch of a proof posed by Shifrin correctly.
I have posted my attempt at a solution as an answer to this question in the hopes of getting feedback/correction (in particular most of the proof ended up being a definition chase and so I feel like, especially in the last steps, I've possibly made some unfounded assumptions), and that it might be helpful to other beginning students of differential geometry with the same question as myself.

Again, I am posting my attempt at a solution as an answer to this question in the hopes of getting feedback/correction (in particular most of the proof ended up being a definition chase and so I feel like, especially in the last steps, I've possibly made some unfounded assumptions), and that it might be helpful to other beginning students of differential geometry with the same question as myself.
What follows is (my attempt at) a detailed version of ideas from both Shifrin and Caniglia, trying to use only concepts that have been presented at this point in do Carmo's text.
Fix $p\in A$. Let $\mathbf{x}_A,\mathbf{x}_S$ denote parametrisations from open sets $U_A,U_S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to neighbourhoods $V_A,V_S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ both containing $p$.
It suffices to show that the inclusion $i_S:A\to S$ is an open mapping, so at each $p\in A$ it suffices to show that $\mathbf{x}_S^{-1}\circ i_S\circ \mathbf{x}_A$ takes a neighbourhood of $q_A = \mathbf{x}_A^{-1}(p)$ to a neighbourhood of $q_S = \mathbb{x}_S^{-1}(p)$, since $\mathbf{x}_A,\mathbf{x}_S$ are (locally) homeomorphisms.
Let $x_S,y_S,z_S$ denote the component functions of $\mathbf{x}_S$. Up to a change of axes, we may assume that the Jacobian determinant $\frac{\partial (x_S,y_S)}{\partial (u,v)}$ is non-zero at $q_S$. Then the function $F:U_S \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$F(u,v,t) = (x_S(u,v), y_S(u,v), z_S(u,v) + t)$$
is smooth with one-to-one derivative at $q_S$. Now applying the inverse function theorem to $F$, we obtain a differentiable inverse $F^{-1}: M \to N$ for neighbourhoods $p \in M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $(q_S, 0) \in N \subset U_S \times \mathbb{R}$. Now letting $\pi: U_S \times \mathbb{R} \to U_S$ be the projection to the first two components, observe that we have the equality
$$\pi\circ F^{-1}\restriction_{M \cap S} = \mathbb{x}^{-1}_S \restriction_{M \cap S}$$
by definition of $F$. (Note: I believe this is now a concrete version of Shifrin's smooth extension of $\mathbf{x}_S^{-1}$, or equivalently resolving differentiability issues by passing first to $\mathbb{R}^3$ as Caniglia discusses.)
Now pick neighbourhoods $p \in A' \subset A$ and $q_A \in U_A'\subset U_A$ such that the inclusion $i: A \to \mathbb{R}^3$ takes $A'$ into $M$, and the parametrisation $\mathbf{x}_A$ takes $U_A'$ into $A'$. Consider the composition
$$\tilde{F} =\pi \circ F^{-1}\circ i\circ\mathbf{x}_A \restriction_{U_A'}.$$
Chasing the definitions we've made, $\tilde{F}$ agrees with $\mathbf{x}_S^{-1}\circ i_S\circ \mathbf{x}_A$ on $U_A'$. It is also differentiable by the chain rule. Finally, the differential $d\tilde{F}_{q_A}$ must be injective. To see this, consider the composition
$$\mathbf{x}_S \circ \tilde{F}$$
which is differentiable by the chain rule, with non-injective differential at $q_A$ if $d\tilde{F}_{q_A}$ is not injective. But recalling our earlier observation, we have
$$\mathbf{x}_S \circ \tilde{F} = i \circ \mathbf{x}_A$$
on our domain of definition $U_A'$, which must have injective differential at $q_A$ since $A$ is a regular surface. Hence the inverse function theorem applies to $\tilde{F}$ which means on some neighbourhood $q_A \in \tilde{U}_A \subset U_A'$,
$$\tilde{F}\restriction_{\tilde{U}_A} = \mathbf{x}_S^{-1}\circ i_S\circ \mathbf{x}_A: \tilde{U}_A \to U_S$$
is an open mapping, which is what we wanted to show.
